# Rest Resources calling problem

Tags: integration, apexrest

I need to help about rest resources. We want to set a job that will come to salesforce and take data that we give by rest resources. However, the problem is that how to call apex rest service from external side. I need permanent token because i won't be able to change it by manuel. Also, it is a need to test this service by restlet(GC extension).

Is there any guide video or something like that step by step?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Understanding Authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm) in the REST API Developer Guide? That will give all information that you need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a `Connected App` that the external caller can use for Authentication purposes.  See some great links below to get started:

1. [Quickstart OAuth with Salesforce Connected App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm) - Step-by-step instructions on how to create your own Connected App in Salesforce for external services use
2. [Web OAuth in Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm) - Explanation of how authentication works
3. [Salesforce REST Explained (example with Postman and authentication)](https://www.veonconsulting.com/salesforce-rest-api-explained/) - End-to-end example of what the external REST call would look like with Authentication

Comment: I wonder that if i get token by this method, can this token be used for a long time?